# expected value of sample median?

Tags: sampling

I am confused regarding a question I'm currently working on.

how do I go about finding the expected value of a sample median?

given that I have 10 balls of which 7 are no. 1's, 2 are no.2's and 1 no.1's. we draw a sample of size 3.
I have found the sampling distribution for the sample median but am unsure how to go about finding the expected value of the sample median in this case.

Comment: Welcome to our site.  Because you have obtained the sampling distribution of the sample median, then you have all the information needed about the expectation.  Could you therefore explain what the obstacle is to finding that expectation?

Comment: am pretty new to estimators. so am unsure how I should go about it. I do know how to find the expected value of a sample mean and that the concept can be applied to sample median as well but am unsure how it works

Comment: Please provide details.  In particular, (a) show us the form in which you have the sampling distribution and (b) show us any steps you have taken to use that form (such as by applying a definition of expectation) to your problem.  For more about this, consult [tag:self-study].

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your statement of the contents of the urn has a typo?
Do you mean seven `1`'s, two `2`'s, and one `3`? Are you sampling without replacement?

I'll assume *Yes* to both 
for purposes of illustration. (If your actual situation is different, you can use similar methods.)

Let $H$ be the value of the median when three balls are drawn.
It is not difficult to see that the median must be either 1 or 2, and that you would have probabilities 
$P(H = 2) = 22/120 = 0.1833$ and $P(H = 1) = 1-P(H=2) = 0.8167.$

Then, from the definition of the expectation of a discrete random variable, you have $$E(H) = 1(98/120) + 2(22/120) = 1.1833.$$

---

A simulation in R, with a million iterations of the 3-draw experiment
gets a suitably similar result. (With a million iterations, one can expect
two or three place accuracy.)

```
set.seed(1007)
m = 10^6;  n = 3;  urn = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1, 2,2, 3)
h = replicate( m, median(sample(urn, n)) )

table(h)/m
h
       1        2 
0.816756 0.183244 
mean(h)
[1] 1.183244
```